# Wildcard character in value in MERGE ON statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a merge statement that starts like this:

```
MERGE INTO TEMSPASA
USING (SELECT *
       FROM OPENQUERY(orad, 'SELECT * FROM CDAS.TDWHCORG')) AS TDWHPASA ON TEMSPASA.pasa_cd = LTRIM(RTRIM(TDWHPASA.corg_id)) AND 
                         TEMSPASA.pasa_active_ind = TDWHPASA.corg_active_ind

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET 
            TEMSPASA.pasa_desc = LTRIM(RTRIM(TDWHPASA.corg_nm)),
            TEMSPASA.pasa_active_ind = TDWHPASA.corg_active_ind

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (pasa_cd, pasa_desc, pasa_active_ind)
    VALUES (LTRIM(RTRIM(TDWHPASA.corg_id)), TDWHPASA.corg_nm, TDWHPASA.corg_active_ind);
```

There are pasa_cd's like ('H04', 'H04*') where that * is NOT a wildcard.  But I think the on statement is treating it like it is a wildcard because when I try to run the merge statement, I get the following error:

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

I have verified that there are no duplicates in my table.  The only thing I can think of is what I mentioned above, that the ON part of the merge statement is seeing that * as a wildcard.

I have tried searching, saw something about an escape character, but that was in the where clause.  Any ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: `=` does not recognize wildcards. `LIKE` does, but "*" is not a wildcard character. `TEMSPASA` or `TDWHPASA` must be matching multiple times given your current criteria.

Comment: Ok, I will keep digging.  I dont see any duplicates in either table.  Even if i export to excel and highlight duplicate values, i get nothing

Comment: Be sure you export to excel AFTER you do your string trims, or at least trim it inside excel.  It may be that the whitespace around terms is what's hiding the duplicates when you highlight in excel.

Comment: Ok, so there were duplicates, sort of.  In my source table there are H04F and H04f, so they are different rows, how do I make my merge statement to be case sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

This means you have more than 1 row that is matching between the source and target tables. You need to find out what row(s) are the issue here. It could be from either table. Something like this should help you identify where the problem is coming from.

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(TDWHPASA.corg_id)) 
    , TDWHPASA.corg_active_ind
FROM CDAS.TDWHCORG as TDWHPASA
group by LTRIM(RTRIM(TDWHPASA.corg_id)) 
    , TDWHPASA.corg_active_ind
having count(*) > 1

select t.pasa_cd
    , t.pasa_active_ind
from TEMSPASA t
group by t.pasa_cd
    , t.pasa_active_ind
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Ok, so there were duplicates, sort of. In my source table there are H04F and H04f, so they are different rows, how do I make my merge statement to be case sensitive?

Comment: I got it, i added  COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS to the end of the ON clause.

Answer (score 1):

So my theory in my initial post was incorrect.  There were duplicates in my source table, but it was based on the case sensitivity.  There were values H04F and H04f.  Both different rows, but because of the case insensitivity in my sql, it was seeing them as duplicates.  To resolve the issue I added  COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS to the end of the ON clause and it did the trick